# SwiftUI CoreData Importing CSV file

Tags: ios, csv, swiftui, core-data, import

i am trying to establish CSV importing to my project. so that when pressing on Import CSV button, it will give user option to choose file and processed to importing and save it to CoreData entity.  But when running the App, the problem is that, after choosing the file, it will give me the selected file name and File Read Successfull, and i am getting error ((  Error the operation could not be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.) )). can please someone help me. i would appreciate it.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import UniformTypeIdentifiers


struct CSVImportView: View {
    
    @State private var document: MessageDocument = MessageDocument(message: "Hello, World!")
    @State private var fileContent: String = ""
    @State private var errorMessage: String = ""
    @State private var showAlert: Bool = false
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    @State private var isImporting: Bool = false
    @State private var file: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button("Import CSV") {
                    isImporting.toggle()
                }
                
                if let file = file {
                    Text("Selected File: \(file.lastPathComponent)")
                    
                    Text(fileContent.isEmpty ? "Cannot read file" : "File Read Successfully")
                        .foregroundColor(fileContent.isEmpty ? .red : .green)
                    
                    // Remove Import Button
                    
                    GroupBox(label: Text("Message:")) {
                        TextEditor(text: $document.message)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("CSV Import")
        }
        .fileImporter(
                    isPresented: $isImporting,
                    allowedContentTypes: [.plainText],
                    allowsMultipleSelection: false
                ) { result in
                    do {
                        guard let selectedFile = try result.get().first else { return }
                        print("Selected File URL:", selectedFile) // Print the selected file URL
                        guard selectedFile.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
                            showAlertWithError(message: "Unable to access the selected file.")
                            return
                        }
                        defer { selectedFile.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }

                        self.file = selectedFile

                        let fileContentData: Data
                        do {
                            fileContentData = try Data(contentsOf: selectedFile)
                        } catch let error {
                            showAlertWithError(message: "Error reading file content: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            return
                        }
                        print("File Content:", fileContentData) // Print the file content after reading

                        guard let message = String(data: fileContentData, encoding: .utf8) else {
                            showAlertWithError(message: "Unable to read file content.")
                            return
                        }
                        document.message = message
                        fileContent = message

                        let parsedData = parseCSV(content: message)
                                        let container = NoteCoreData.shared.persistentContainer

                                        saveToCoreData(parsedData: parsedData, with: container) { success, message in
                                            if success {
                                                showAlert = true
                                                errorMessage = message // Update message to indicate success
                                            } else {
                                                showAlert = true
                                                errorMessage = message // Display error message
                                                print("Error saving data:", message)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        print("Parsed Data:", parsedData)
                       // importCSV(url: selectedFile)

                    } catch let fileError as NSError {
                        print("File error:", fileError.localizedDescription)
                        showAlertWithError(message: "File Error: \(fileError.localizedDescription)")
                    } catch {
                        showAlertWithError(message: error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
            }
    
    func importCSV(url: URL) {
        do {
            let content = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
            let parsedData = parseCSV(content: content)
            let container = NoteCoreData.shared.persistentContainer

            saveToCoreData(parsedData: parsedData, with: container) { success, message in
                if success {
                    showAlert = true
                    errorMessage = message // Update message to indicate success
                } else {
                    showAlert = true
                    errorMessage = message // Display error message
                    print("Error saving data:", message)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            showAlertWithError(message: error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func parseCSV(content: String) -> [Note] {
            var parsedData: [Note] = []
            let rows = content.components(separatedBy: "\n")

            let possibleDateFormats = ["MM/dd/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"]

            for row in rows {
                let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")

                if columns.count >= 3 {
                    let title = columns[0]
                    let dateString = columns[1]
                    let noteContent = columns[2]

                    if let date = tryFixingDate(dateString, possibleDateFormats: possibleDateFormats) {
                        let note = Note()
                        note.title = title
                        note.date = date
                        note.noteContent = noteContent
                        parsedData.append(note)
                    } else {
                        print("Unable to convert date:", dateString)
                    }
                } else if !row.isEmpty {
                    print("Incomplete row:", row)
                }
            }

            return parsedData
        }
  
    func saveToCoreData(parsedData: [Note], with container: NSPersistentContainer, completion: @escaping (Bool, String) -> Void) {
           let context = container.viewContext

           for note in parsedData {
               let newNote = Note(context: context)
               newNote.userID = "UniqueUserID"
               newNote.id = UUID()
               newNote.title = note.title
               newNote.date = note.date
               newNote.noteContent = note.noteContent
               newNote.dataType = "Note"
           }

           do {
               try context.save()
               completion(true, "Data saved successfully!") // Data saved successfully
           } catch {
               completion(false, error.localizedDescription) // Error occurred during saving
           }
       }

    func tryFixingDate(_ dateString: String, possibleDateFormats: [String]) -> Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        for format in possibleDateFormats {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
            if let parsedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
                return parsedDate
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    
    // Function to show alert with error message
      func showAlertWithError(message: String) {
          errorMessage = message
          showAlert = true
          print("Error:", message)
      }

}
struct MessageDocument: FileDocument {
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.plainText] }
    var message: String

    init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        message = string
    }

    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: message.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi . I recommend using a real CSV parser, might save you and your users some heartache if/when their CSV has escaped/quoted values: https://github.com/swiftcsv/SwiftCSV. Might also help you manage/solve your original problem here. Good luck.

Comment: What line of code does this error occur on?

Comment: Print `error`, not `error.localizedDescription` only. You can show an alert to the user with the localizedDescription, but as a developper, print the full error, as you'll get full infos. Also you need to tell us which line throw the error we can't guess as there are plenty of possibilities...

Comment: that error i am getting when Running the app

Comment: @KineticNetwork To track down an error, it's important to know when **exactly** the error happens. You have a lot of lines of code here. One of them is causing this error. You could help people to help you if you can find out which one.

Comment: We understand that it’s a runtime error but on what code line did the error occur? How far did the code execute before it crashed?

Comment: There is no error in lines. the app is running. Xcode does not warn on any specific line that has errors. but when i added :  let parsedData = parseCSV(content: message) OR importCSV(url: selectedFile) i started to get that type of error message:  (( Error the operation could not be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.) )).  have any body tried to Run it from their side?

Comment: In `importCSV(...)`, add `print(error)` in the `catch`, and show us what it prints.

Comment: Use the debugger then to step through parseCSV to find that row (or add print statements inside the function if you don’t know how to use the debugger). It should not be impossible to find the exact row.